# Using Javascript to read the file names of the current directory

Tags: javascript

Is there a way for an html document using Javascript to read the file names of the current and sub directories?

I understand that for security reasons this may be a restricted functionality, but im looking not using this as a served application - rather locally residing HTML files in each directory to log the contents. Looking at the following scenerio...

We have a directory tree structure with multiple sub directories, each with hundreds of files (logically named) - and we maintain logs for these files in xls format.  If i could have an HTML file in these directories using javascrpipt, i could dynamically create this logs rather than manually maintaining them.

thanks...

Comment: The force will never be with you in this case.

Comment: You can't do this with HTML and JavaScript alone. If you used PHP with JavaScript it would be possible.

Comment: Yes, easy to do with PHP - but this is not a web server environment.  This is a local file server environment - im trying to think outside the box a little and use HTML/Javascript to automate a relatively tedious task.  I feel like i should be able to use HTML and Javascript for "other than web development" purposes.

Comment: And i up voted Amits response for the laughter - much needed.

Comment: You need a server side application to dynamically get the path of current and sub directories. To simplify, one usually uses a template mechanism that you may find or build by yourself with any server side application language you wish to use.

Comment: More context is needed. Where/how is the JavaScript executed?

Comment: Felix - I mentioned the javascript is in an html file on our local server.  I would place the file in each of our main directories to catalog its contents.  Another-words, this is not a web server or web application.   This is an attempt to automatically generate logs from locally stored files, for internal use only.

Comment: But does that also mean that the HTML file would not even be accessed via a web browser? It seems to me what you need is simply a server side script that iterates over the file system and produces a report in whatever format you want.

Comment: This is not a web host.  Its a generic file server, there is no server side script support. yes, it would be simple with PHP for me. The HTML file would be viewed with IE, FF or Chrome. the benefit to me would be the ability to program in filtering, searching, report generating, linking, etc...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good example of how you can do that and don't die trying: http://www.c-point.com/JavaScript/articles/file_access_with_JavaScript.htm